# Bad Request : Did not attempt to load JSON data because the request Content-Type was not 'application/json'

Tags: javascript, python, flask, fetch-api

I'm using React as frontend and Flask as the backend here. I am sending a JSON file from react to flask using POST method with proper headers. But I keep on getting this error : Bad Request
Did not attempt to load JSON data because the request Content-Type was not 'application/json'.
Here is my React code which sends the JSON file to the backend where obj = an object saved in the localstorage of the browser.

` frontend code :

```
let obj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('selectedMovies'));
    const sendMovieId = async () => {
        try{
          let res = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/moviesSent' , {
            method : 'POST',
            headers : {
              'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
            },
            body : JSON.stringify(obj)
          });
          if(res.status === 200){
            navigate('/secondPage');
          }
        }catch(e){
          console.log(e);
        }
      }

      useEffect(() => {
        if(obj['data'].length !== 0){
          sendMovieId();
        }else{
          console.log('data not reloaded');
        }
    
        if(localStorage.getItem('moviesSelectedStatus')){
          navigate('/secondPage');
        }
      });
```

`

` Flask Code :

```
@app.route("/moviesSent" , methods=['GET','POST'])
def get_movies_recommended():
    # content_type = request.headers.get('Content-Type')
    movies = request.json
    data = movies["data"] 
    return json.dumps({"movies" : data})
```

`

Answer (score 0):

I cant add a question in the comment section yet because of lack of rep, so I'm going to ask you something here. If you have an object in localStorage, isn't it already stringified? And if it is then that means you're sending an object inside of a string inside of a string ""{...}"". I haven't tested this locally, but it seems like that could potentially cause some unexpected behavior. Can you try just passing through just the `obj` not `JSON.stringify(obj)`?